# Using the bootstrap modal in the angular2, closing modal will shake

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal

When I open the window, the page wider, I think it is the problem of the scroll bar, could you tell me how to solve in angular2?

it is a list:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let interview of interviews;" role="row" class="gradeA">
      <td class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.company.name }}</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.inviter.real_name }}</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.interviewee.user_id==0">未知</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.interviewee.user_id!=0">{{ interview.interviewee.real_name }}</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.notice_type==0">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" (click)="showModal(interview)">短信</a>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.notice_type==1">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" (click)="showModal(interview)">邮件</a>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.interview_time }}</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.status==0">发起面试</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.status==1">确认面试时间</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.status==2">面试完成</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.status==3">面试者没有参加面试</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">通知内容</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="selectedInterview !== undefined">
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">公司名称：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.company.name }}</p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">面试官：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.inviter.real_name }}</p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">应聘者：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.interviewee.real_name }}</p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">通知内容：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.notice_content }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

showmodal method:

```
selectedInterview: any;
showModal(interviewObj) {
this.selectedInterview = interviewObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not `Angular` issue, its `CSS` problem. Try to give the parent div some width. If you could share your code then it will be easier to solve the problem.